# XMLHttpRequest Object wants to .open file one folder up?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an `XMLHttpRequest` Object that is trying to access a file outside of it's folder.

W3Schools says that: For security reasons, modern browsers do not allow access across domains.

This means that both the web page and the XML file it tries to load, must be located on the same server.

So, my file is on the same server. just in a different directory (folder.) It’s not reading the file. Is there a workaround for this?

The javascript file works perfectly when the .xml file is located in the same folder. However, I want to access it from outside the folder - one directory up. i used the syntax ../ to indicate that it is located one file up. it doesn't seem to get access to it...

1 works perfectly with myFile.xml located in the same folder.

2 does not seem to be able to locate myFile.xml in the directory that the folder is located in.

Using the direct path does not work.

1.)    xmlhttp.open("GET", "myFile.xml", true);

2.)    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../myFile.xml", true);

[EDIT - Update] solved. It works. Exactly as is. I moved the files over to the host server from my desktop folder. I still don't know why there's a different outcome from the desktop environment... but, I'm glad to know I was coding it correctly.

Comment: Relative path should work. Provide more details on your issue. Otherwise your question is off-topic

Comment: "Is there a workaround for this?" — You need to identify the problem before you can think about trying to solve it. You've already spent two and a half paragraphs determining that they aren't on different origins. Look at the developer tools in your browser. Look at the network tab. Look at the URL you are actually requesting. Look at the response you get for it.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma — Why would using a proxy help? It's the same origin.

Comment: "Using the direct path does not work" — What is the direct path?

Comment: "one directory up" — Where is one directory up? Would it happen to be *above* the root directory of your web server? So the XML file, rather than being on a different server, isn't on any HTTP server at all and doesn't have a URL?

Comment: I'm working on my desktop, in a folder on my desktop. the myFile.xml is located in the file on my desktop and the myFile.js is located in a folder within that folder. I did try hosting the myFile.xml and linking it from the url.... but that seems to definitely violate the browser's cross directory limitations. wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on my desktop, in a folder on my desktop.

Most browsers forbid XMLHttpRequest access to file: URIs entirely.

Firefox allows access with [certain restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs):

> a file can read another file only if the parent directory of the originating file is an ancestor directory of the target file.

Since the file you are trying to read is in a directory *above* the one containing the HTML document you are trying to access it from, permission is denied.

To avoid this limitation, don't try to use XMLHttpRequest without HTTP.

Comment: is it inappropriate to ask for an example, or maybe a reference article? I very much appreciate your help and input. and thank you!

Comment: "an example" — of what?

Comment: "don't try to use XMLHttpRequest without HTTP" Does this mean I should use a reference to it from the host site?